# Scalability issues in NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, sockets, scalability

We are running a NodeJS express based server to handle incoming requests from Particle Photon based devices. The communication between the server and devices is encrypted where we use decrypto libraries in NodeJS. We are running the server on a 4-core 8GB machine, using NodeJS v0.10.25 and currently receiving 220 requests per-second (each with about 1kB of data). We use PM2 for load-balancing as well. For every request received, we emit an event to process it (which goes into the single event queue of NodeJS?)

But it seems that NodeJS with PM2 is not able to handle this load. It works for some time but is not able to process all events in-time. After accumulating a lot of pending requests, it stops any incoming packets and keeps processing the data/events that it had queued up.

1. Are there scalability issues persisting with NodeJS servers? Is NodeJS not meant for this heavy load? Is it because of using a very old NodeJS version (we are a bit paranoid about upgrading due to dependencies)?
   Also,
2. What is the best tool for Load Balancing NodeJS (can we get better performance using something other than PM2)?
3. What is the mechanism (libraries, code or tools) that we can use for analyzing stats regarding NodeJS v8 engine. Especially, we need more info about the number of event loops under the V8 engine (which I think is just 1) and the count/nature of events in the event loops that are pending at any point in time.
4. Is this a known issue of NoseJS disconnecting from sockets and halting incoming requests if the event loop queue is overloaded? Is there a way to configure this behavior?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using the latest stable NodeJS version (4.3.2) fixed the issue.

Comment: For your interest, the latest LTS version is 6.9.5. You're probably better off using the latest LTS. Version 4.3.2 was released March 3, 2016 so is pretty outdated and might contain security vulnerabilities.